# When Using OVER with COUNT, What Does It Mean to Use Two Arguments With PARTITION BY?

Tags: sql, window-functions

```
SELECT
     M.Listing_ID, 
     COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY M.User_ID,EXTRACT(MONTH FROM M.Start_Date) 
                     ORDER BY M.Start_Date, M.Listing_ID ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) X
FROM LISTINGS M
```

Here is `LISTINGS`:

Listings

```
User_ID   Listing_ID         Start_Date
A             1              2014-02-14
A             2              2014-03-10
A             3              2014-03-22
B             4              2014-06-08
B             5              2014-10-02
C             6              2014-09-04
C             7              2014-09-04
C             8              2014-09-04
C             9              2014-09-05
C             10             2014-10-03
```

I'm trying to decode what this code returns but I don't really know what it means to partition by 2 catagories. Can someone shed light?

Comment: It's the same difference as between `group by x` and `group by x,y`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get the number of rows, `COUNT`, by user and by month. The `PARTITION BY` tells the database when to reset the count

Comment: I think you can sign it as the correct answer anyway